# Adding Employee record into Quickbooks system using SDK

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I'm using Quickbooks SDK to add employee records but it seems the SDK provides limited number of fields but I want to add information like "Ethnicity", "Disability", "US Veteran" etc.

```
IMsgSetRequest messageSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 12, 0);
IEmployeeAdd empAdd = messageSet.AppendEmployeeAddRq();
empAdd.LastName.SetValue(employee.LastName);
empAdd.FirstName.SetValue(employee.FirstName);
....
 empAdd.Ethnicity /// No such property available
....
IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(messageSet);
```

Is it possible to add such field using QB SDK?

**UPDATE:**

QB employee screen attached:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are those custom fields you have set up in QuickBooks? QuickBooks doesn't have any built-in field for veteran, etc....

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmer-consolibyte, thanks for your comment. These are not custom fields. However, API provides a way to update custom fields. It seems the API can only access limited number of attributes. I'm curious how other third party library works

Comment: You can update custom fields with the API. You can't just invent random made-up fields and expect them to work though. Where are you getting that "Ethnicity" field from? It's not in the docs anywhere...

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte, Probably you did not get my point. These fields exist in QB but not available via API call. Please see attached screen. I just installed QB and can see these fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to the [QuickBooks OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for reference as to which fields are supported.

If the fields are not in the OSR, then they are not supported via the API.

Neither Ethnicity, Disability, nor US Veteran are fields that the API supports.

Comment: OK, so then you know it's not supported?

Comment: Yes. I know there is no such option via their API. But like to if there is any workaround for that.

Comment: Outside of adding a custom field and using that instead, no.